# Getting number around an array of consecutive numbers

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say i have the following arrays in PHP:

```
$array1 = array(5,6);
$array2 = array(89,90,91);
$array3 = array(75,76,77,78);
$array4 = array(3);
$array5 = array(65,64,63);
```

I need a function which will get the numbers around the numbers in array, the output should be as following:

```
$array1around = getAround($array1); // Result: array(4, 7);
$array2around = getAround($array2); // Result: array(88, 92);
$array3around = getAround($array3); // Result: array(74, 79);
$array4around = getAround($array4); // Result: array(2,4);
$array5around = getAround($array5); // Result: array(62,65);
```

Is it possible without playing around with -1 and +1 for min and max? I would like to see the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getAround($array)
{
  return [min($array) - 1 ,max($array) + 1] ;
}
```

This is the code you need, of course if you have some arrays run on them with a loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getAround(array $a) {
  if (count($a) <= 1) {
    return $a;
  }

  sort($a);

  return [$a[0] - 1, $a[count($a) - 1] + 1];
}
```

But it is better to use `min()` and `max()` functions as in the accepted answer, for better performance.

Comment: sort is O(nlogn), while max is O(n)

Comment: This will not work if the array has consecutive numbers but in wrong order.

Comment: @PHPLover, `62,66`. Try it yourself.

Comment: Ah okay sorry you have the sort function.

Answer (score 1):

in your case (elements in sort order):

```
function getAround($array)
{
  return [$array[0] - 1, $array[count($array) - 1] + 1);
}
```

Edit(after the edit of this question):

If that use `max($array) + 1` and `min($array) - 1`.

Comment: what about if the numbers are not in correct order? (Check my last edit)